# Promoting Heroku app from staging to production keeps environment

Tags: heroku, heroku-pipelines

Say I have an environment variable called API_URL, which I set 2 different values for staging and production.

Thing is: when I promote the app from staging to production, it keeps staging API_URL value in the production environment, though in Settings it's set to the right value.

Does anyone know how to disable this "feature"?

Comment: That's not something that Heroku does by default. How are you using the environment variables? Are you using something like [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) that compiles them into the application at build time?

Comment: Yeah, something like (Webpack). The build from production was created with the environment variables from staging, which are completely different from each other.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect. If your code doesn't actually look at environment variables at runtime why would they have any effect? You probably need to build your code again with the new variables instead of promoting your slug through pipelines.

Comment: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/545

Comment: https://github.com/mars/heroku-js-runtime-env

Comment: @Chris Oh, I assumed a build was being generated from the promotion. I thought it was getting the latest commit pushed and build it all again. Seems obvious now that you mentioned, but this promotion thing doesn't fit the expectation (mine at least) since I use it to split environments.

Comment: Now I understand your confusion. [Promoting from one stage to the next](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines#deployment-with-pipelines) "ensures that production contains the exact same code that you tested in staging, and it’s also much faster than rebuilding the slug". If you want to build your code again you can do that, e.g. by pushing code to your production dyno(s) or by having them [automatically build from a specified GitHub branch](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#automatic-deploys).